# How do I execute multiple processes simultaneously in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on an application in which I want multiple tasks to be executed simultaneously.

I also want to be able to keep track of the number of such tasks being run in parallel, and sometimes add yet another task to be processed in parallel, in addition to the current set of tasks already being processed.

One more thing- I want to do the above, not only in a desktop app, but also in a cloud app, in which I initialise another virtual machine running Tomcat, and then repeat all of the above in that instance.

What is the best way to do this? If you can point me to the correct theory/guides on this subject, that would be great, although code samples are also welcome.

Comment: have you heard of threads? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: no, he wants tasks, not threads

Comment: you mean different address space for each of the tasks?

Comment: @Eugene, I think he wants threads, and called them tasks.

Comment: He has a lot of reputation in Java. He knows what thread is.

Comment: From the brief description which includes initialising and managing another VM or JVM, I think this is moving outside of Java coding scope. The issue you are facing has moved to architectural level, where the solution will involve more than plain Java coding.

Comment: Not only desktop but also cloud? Way too broad. But see river.apache.org.

Comment: i do know threads at a conceptual level, however i am not sure if threads can be applied to the kind of distributed app i am looking to create, viz can i start/control threads on a remote machine in a cloud app? ...

Comment: I agree with the "too broad" assessment. Creating a task execution engine that can be managed remotely involves too many moving parts to allow for a concise answer explaining what to do, especially based on a description as vague as this. Seems to me like you're not really clear on what you ultimately want to accomplish with this. (Or you're leaving out the details from your question.)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure "I want to start / stop threads in a Tomcat instance" makes sense as a requirement. Tomcat generally manages threads as incoming requests require it, why would you want to poke at its internals like this?

Answer (score 6):

Concurrency is a huge topic in Java, please take your time for it

[Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Concurrency in a Java program is accomplished by starting your own [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). Multiple processes can only be realized with multiple JVMs. When you are done with the basics, you want to take a look at [Executors.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) They will help to implement your application in a structured way since they abstract from *Threads* to *Tasks*.

I don't know how much time you have planned for this, but if you are really at the start, get [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/), read it and write a kick-ass concurrent Java application.

Raising the whole thing to a distributed level is a whole other story. You cannot tackle that all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... What a series of steps.  Start by extending [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), then using [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) to run and manage your Jobs.  After that, you can get into Tomcat.