# Monitoring folders simentainously is not happening

Tags: java

Iam implementing an application, which needs to monitor folders simultainously and sends the report if any changes happened in the folders.
Lets take.
Here under parent folder there will be 6 child folders. I will get child folders name in an String array, if i iterate using for loop and monitor, it is like, monitoring them one after other. But i have monitor all at a once simultainously.

How can i do this, please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Please post relevant code :) As it stands your q is likely very hard to answer.

Comment: down voters please add your comments for downvoting

Comment: I did not DV, but I guess it is because your question is hard to understand. Please post relevant code, where you think your problem might lie etc. Even after this, it might be too broad a q.

Answer (score 1):

You need the NIO watch service.

Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html for a tutorial.

Comment: i used the same to monitor api for monitoring of floders, my question is how can i monitor at the same time all the child folders

Comment: Walk the file tree and create monitors on any folders you discover:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of threads, Hope this link will help you
                                                               http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/

Secondly, you can check out this as well to get an idea how to run simultaneous tasks

[How do I execute multiple processes simultaneously in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892740/how-do-i-execute-multiple-processes-simultaneously-in-java)